# How can the amount of dielectric material affect a PCB?

Tags: capacitor, pcb-design

So I understand that the dielectric material on a PCB (i.e. FR-4) can affect the capacitance of the board. The thinner the material, the larger capacitance between the layers on the board. What I don't understand is why is that capacitance significant, and in what applications should the amount of dielectric material be taken into consideration?

Comment: Why do you think that capacitance wouldn't be significant?

Comment: How much capacitance is significant or insignificant to you? Sometimes you just need a tolerace for some parameter that depends on capacitance, say RC filter. If R is large and C is small, then small capacitance that the PCB adds is significant. Is this a homework question by the way?

Comment: @Justme No, lol. I was just curious as to how a PCB's capacitance would affect a circuit. I learned about this on an internship last year, and wanted to learn more about the actual effects.

Answer (score 5):

The capacitance formed between copper planes in different board layers is typically much smaller than the capacitance from discrete capacitors. but it has a very low parasitic series inductance and therefore is the most important capacitance for frequencies above a few 100 MHz. This frequency range is important for decoupling fast ICs or for handling ESD.

The capacitance between a trace and the plane underneath is important for transmission line impedance. A thinner dielectric reduces the characteristic impedance at the same dimensions. therefore trace dimensions can be smaller for the same characteristic impedance, which facilitates dense high speed routing.

Answer (score 2):

Any dielectric between any two conductors is basically a capacitor, and the capacitance is determined by the area of the conductors, the distance between conductors, and the dielectric material between them.

This also applies to wires in cables and copper wires on PCB is no exception - basically a PCB that has a solid copper plane on both sides is just a capacitor too.

The thickness of the PCB affects the capacitance, so a thinner PCB has more capacitance between planes.

The wider the tracks are, there is more area between them so more capacitance.

In some specialized circuits (radiofrequency boards) the PCB material can be chosen to have a more suitable dielectric constant than FR-4 has.

Imagine building a RC or LC oscillator, or even connecting a microcontroller to a crystal that requires 20 picofarads of load capacitance. Since the wires from MCU to crystal have already few picofarads of unwanted stray capacitance, you need to adjust the actual crystal load capacitors to a lower value to take the PCB wiring capacitance into account.

High frequency and high impedance circuits are more affected by stray PCB capacitance.